# How can I select a HTML element that is pushed after page loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

As you know, for the HTML which is pushed into document after page loading, this won't work:

```
$('.myclass').on('click', function(){

})
```

And we have to write it like this to work:

```
$(document).on('click', '.myclass', function(){

})
```

---

Ok all fine, now I want to know how should I write following code to work for the HTML that is pushed later ?

```
$(".myclass").on({
    focusout: function() {
    },
    keydown: function(ev) {
    }
})
```

Comment: break it up into two

Comment: An event listener will only work for elements that existed when the event listener was created. If you add new elements and want events to trigger off of them, you have to re-create the listener.

Answer (score 0):

Split it into two parts

```
$(document).on('focusout', '.myclass', function(){

});
$(document).on('keydown', '.myclass', function(ev){

});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you put a jQuery event listener on the `document` it will listen for changes in the document and apply event listeners to matching selectors. This should be used if you dynamically add content to the DOM.

You will probably want break it into two separate event listeners:

```
$(document).on('focusout', '.myclass', function(){
    //...
})

$(document).on('keydown', '.myclass', function(){
    //...
})
```

If you want the exact function to run on both `focuseout` and `keydown` you can add as many events as you want:

```
$(document).on('focusout keydown', '.myclass', function(){
    //...
})
```